# Enable CORS in console application server

Tags: .net, cors, console-application

I am using .net console application as a REST server, with services wrapped by WebServiceHost objects. How can I enable CORS on this server, or on these services. This is NOT an asp.net application at all, just console application. Thanks.

Comment: what did you do ? there is no clear answer for console applications

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your VS Project.
2. Open **Package Manager Console** (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)
3. Type the following command
     **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors**
4. Open **Startup.cs** or **App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs**
5. Add this namesace "**using System.Web.Http.Cors**"
6. Add this code to Startup 's -> Configuration method or WebApiConfig 's -> Register method

   ```
       EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(cors);
   ```

More about this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api